# How can I iterate through variables?

Tags: c++, iteration

If I have the code:

```
T a;
T b;
T c;
// ...
T z;
```

How can I iterate through them without creating `std::vector<T&>` of them?

Any beautiful solution, something like (pseudo):

```
for (auto& it : [a, b, c, d, e, f]) {
    // ...
}
```

(Without copies.)

Comment: you can't even create a `std::vector<T&>`.

Comment: Generally you can't. You can create a temporary vector containing *copies of the values* of the variables though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - this will copy the variables, yes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17660354/2124148

Comment: You might want to reconsider why you are using so many variables here though. What is the purpose of the code? What is the *actual* problem you want so solve? Maybe even rethink your design?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have a struct like `struct address_t { string state, string city, string street, ... }` and now I need to join all its *non-empty* parts to `string fulladdress`.

Comment: Just to add, @juanchopanza and others, you actually **can** create a vector of reference *wrappers*. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for (auto& var : {std::ref(a), std::ref(b), std::ref(c), std::ref(d), std::ref(e), std::ref(f)}) {
    // ...
}
```

Should do the job.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't simply write `for (auto it : {&a, &b, &c}) ...` ?

Comment: @H.Guijt: To have a more transparent usage (you have to dereference `it`), but it is a valid alternative.

Comment: `var` is then const and can not be modified, correct? why?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to actually modify the "variables" then you might be able do something like

```
// TODO: Put your own variables here, in the order you want them
auto variables = { a, b, c, .... };

// Concatenate all strings
std::string result = std::accumulate(std::begin(variables), std::end(variables), "",
    [](std::string const& first, std::string const& second)
    {
        return first + ' ' + second;  // To add spacing
    });
```

Note that this requires all "variables" to be of the same type (`std::string`). If you have a variable that is not a string you can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert them in the first step.

Comment: Your `initializer_list` does a copy.

Comment: @Jarod42 And in most cases it's really nothing to worry about. We don't know the use-case of the OP, if the OP is doing this multiple times a second then yes it might be an issue. If the OP is doing once or twice during a ten-hour run-time then it's really insignificant. It's all about context (which we don't have). If this is measured to be a bottleneck then maybe use `std::cref` instead.

Comment: OP stated explicitly, *"(Without copies.)"*. But I mostly agree in practice.