# Is there any way to iterate through a struct?

Tags: c++

I would like to iterate through a struct which is defined in other library whose source is not under my control. So any lib which requires to define the struct with its own macros/adaptors like [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660095/iterating-over-a-struct-in-c) is not usable here. I found the closest way is using `boost::hana`. However, it still requires to fill up an adaptor before I can iterate through it. I attached an [example here.](https://godbolt.org/z/oajjj5) I wonder is there any way I can automate the `BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT` then I do not need to fill up all the struct member names in there (those structs in total have more than hundred members).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>
namespace hana=boost::hana;
struct adapt_test
{
    std::string name;
    int data;
};
BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    adapt_test
    , name
    , data
);
auto names = hana::transform(hana::accessors<adapt_test>(), hana::first);
int main() {
    hana::for_each(
        names, 
        [] (auto item)
        {
            std::cout << hana::to<char const *>(item) << std::endl;
        }
    );
    adapt_test s1{"a", 2};
    hana::for_each(
        s1, 
        [] (auto pair)
        {
        std::cout << hana::to<char const *>(hana::first(pair)) << "=" << hana::second(pair) << std::endl;
        }
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't need name, and if structure has some properties (constexpr aggregate initializable and must not contain references nor bitfields), [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) might help.

Comment: Else you can still write a script to generate the adaptator.

Comment: Fixed `throw`="through". `throw` is a C++ keyword (throwing exceptions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over a struct in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660095/iterating-over-a-struct-in-c)

Comment: @Jarod42 the magic_get is very interesting.

Comment: @Wyck please read first 2 sentence in my post. That post apparently does not meet those requirement.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Boost Flat Reflection](http://apolukhin.github.io/magic_get/index.html) like:

```
struct adapt_test
{
    std::string name;
    int data;
};
adapt_test s1{"a", 2};

std::cout << boost::pfr::get<0>(s1)  << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::pfr::get<1>(s1)  << std::endl;

boost::pfr::flat_for_each_field(s1, [] (const auto& field) { std::cout << field << std::endl; } );
```

P.S. Respect for [@apolukhin](https://github.com/apolukhin) for this library.

Comment: The only thing missing is to get the field name. I guess this is rather difficult. Any insight about this?

Comment: @Wang I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: It is a cool library, but without names it is nearly useless.

Comment: @Wang C++ don't have real reflection yet. If you need names it seems like only solution is construct a wrapper std::tuple<  > self-made type meta, i.e. `auto meta = std::make_tuple( std::make_pair("name", s1.name), std::make_pair("data", s1.data)); ` and then use `boost::hana::tuple_for_each`

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question is **no**.

C++ does not treat identifiers as string literal (it could be indeed useful in some cases), and there is no bridge unfortunately between these kind of strings.

Hopefully, some standard one day will bring this ability, relieving us from having to go through macros or code generation, or maybe doing differently like this: telling "please treat my `struct A { int x, y; }` as a pair", where the meaning would be to match type of `first` and `second` to the members `x` and `y` and then building the types so that it works, it would be really useful for tuples as well. A kind of structured template matching.

Currently the best that can be done to my knowledge is to match structs to tuple without the names (as of C++17) because of the above limitation, such as with `boost::hana` or `boost::fusion` as you do.