# Accessing fields of struct iteratively

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Let's say I have a struct defined as follows:

```
struct Record
{
  string a;
  string b;
  string c;
};
```

I also have a `vector<Record>` containing some data.  I am writing a function which will take a `Record` and a `vector<Record>` as input, and I have to return all entries in the `vector` which match with the `Record`.

However, in the `Record` that will be passed as a parameter to the function, some of the entries will be initialised to `""`. This means that those entries should not be considered while comparing with entries in the `vector`.

I have currently written the function as follows:

```
vector<Record> SearchQuery (vector<Record> data, Record tosearch)
{
    if (tosearch.a != "")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            if (data[i].entryno != tosearch.a)
            {
                data.erase(data.begin() + i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    . 
    . // I can duplicate the above part for entry b and c as well
}
```

However, this doesn't seem like a good manner to write the code, as there will be a lot of redundancy. Also if `Record` has a lot of member variables, then the code will be huge. My question is that is there a better way to fulfill the requirement I have mentioned above?

I have looked at accessing member variables through macros, but it seems that won't work out. Accessing member variables through an index for the ith variable in a struct also seems problematic. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through Struct and Class Members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059157/iterate-through-struct-and-class-members)

Comment: Do you not have access to the Record code? If you do, you should implement your compare function in it.

Comment: @o_weisman Yup, I think that should do it. I now feel stupid for not having thought of it earlier.

Comment: @o_weisman You don't even have to modify the `Record` code. You can implement a non member comparison function and use it with e.g. `std::copy_if`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, that is true :) . Personally I like the tighter coupling between object and comparison but your suggestion has greater flexibility.