# Check if two instances of my class are equal using templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, velocity

I want to check if two instances of my class are equal(in C++), there are no pointers in the class. I understand that I would need to override the = operator and manually check all the fields. I am aware of that solution. The problem is that I have like around 100 members in the class, and I would want to do it for many classes of similar sizes.

My questions is if there is a way to templatize this? Is this possible? I am fine using velocity.

Comment: (You want to override the `==` operator.) How similar ate these classes? You may consider inheritance. And maybe rethink your approach as 100 members are often avoidable (not always).

Comment: C++ does not support reflection.  You would need some preprocessor assisted solution, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059157/iterate-through-struct-and-class-members

Comment: If the members are all POD, you could use `memcmp`. Otherwise just don't have such huge classes. Perhaps a change in design.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217911/why-dont-c-compilers-define-operator-and-operator

Comment: Why is this tagged velocity

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [`std::tuple`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/). The obvious drawback is that you need to refer to your members by [`std::get<size_t>()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/operators/).