# print any struct in template function

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have 3 or more struct , and I want that I have one function for print any struct

for example :

```
struct A 
{
  int a0;
  string a1;
  bool a2;
}
```

and

```
struct B
{
 CString b0;
 double b1;
 int b2;
 string b3
}
```

I want print this struct ( A and B) with same function

like this :

```
template<typename T>
inline void print(T)
{
  std::cout << // I don't know what is write here....
}
```

any body help me?

Comment: How do you expect the `print` function to know *how* to print the contents? C++ doesn't have reflection (yet)

Comment: Look around for *reflection*. Unfortunately C++ doesn't have it natively (yet), but there are library implementations such as Boost.Fusion which generate the necessary metadata with a bit of user help.

Comment: You just want to use the same name or `print`ing, or do you want the function to divine the contents of the structure like UnholySheep asked?

Comment: @Quentin can you explain about reflection? what is this?

Comment: Probably duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059157/iterate-through-struct-and-class-members

Comment: @StoryTeller no I want print

Comment: @Joo - Yes, you already said that. I asked you to clarify what does "I want print" means. Is it to have a common interface, or an actual unique entry point.

Comment: @Joo a good keyword to input into your favorite search engine :) -- Reflection is the ability to (at least) list the contents of objects automatically, which is what you're looking for. But the discussion goes much further, so I encourage you to pursue your research.

Comment: @StoryTeller it's common interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, another solution is to make a function called `to_string` for example (this is to directly convert your struct to string, but the performance is not good)

```
struct A
{
  int a0;
  string a1;
  bool a2;

  string to_string() const {
      return "{ " + std::to_string(a0) + ", " + a1 + ", " + (a2 ? "true" : "false") + " }";
  }
};
```

Then

```
template<typename T>
void print(const T &a) {
    cout << a.to_string() << "\n";
}
```

This is not good for printing, for printing, use the C++ convention of implementing `operator<<`

But.

This have a disadvantage, when an subclass want to change the output format. It can't.

So

```
class DynamicallyToStringConvertible {
public:
    virtual string to_string() const = 0;
    virtual ~DynamicallyToStringConvertible() {}
};

struct A: DynamicallyToStringConvertible
{
    ...
    virtual string to_string() const {
        return "{ " + std::to_string(a0) + ", " + a1 + ", " + (a2 ? "true" : "false") + " }";
    }
}

struct SubclassFromA: public A {
    virtual string to_string() const {
        return "Subclass: " + A::to_string();
    }
};
```

The function `print` is as is

Then

```
void tryPrintingAsA(const A &a) {
    print(a);
}
```

You will find now (after virtual functions), this will work for SubclassA.
But if you tried the `operator<<` or the beginning of the solution (to_string without virtual), it will work for SubclassA as it was a vanilla A.

Then you would make something like that

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, const DynamicallyToStringConvertible &p) {
    return s << p.to_string();
}
```

Inside your Base class, like this:

```
class DynamicallyToStringConvertible {
public:
    virtual string to_string() const = 0;
    virtual ~DynamicallyToStringConvertible() {}

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, const DynamicallyToStringConvertible &p) {
        return s << p.to_string();
    }
};
```

Now try the printing function for A to be:

```
void tryPrintingAsA(const A &a) {
    cout << a;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Usual practice in C++ is to define `operator<<(std::ostream &, const T &)` for your type:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &value)
{
    // print here
    return os;
}
```

This should be done for each type you want to print and this function should be defined in the same namespace as that type.

After that, your data types can be printed to all output stream. This also allows things like `boost::lexical_cast` to work with your type as it prints value to `std::stringstream` internally.

Comment: @Joo Manually for each data type. Were asking for how to iterate over all fields? Because I don't see that being mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Joo If you actually need to _print_ it (e.g. need this for debugging or logging), then I strongly suggest you doing this manually. Custom printing can be way more useful than something automatically generated.