# Is there a way to loop over different data members of an object in C++

Tags: c++

If I have a class object comprised of 3 doubles; x, y and z, is there a way to loop over them in a function?

e.g.

```
for(i in (x,y,z))
    do something;
```

I can do something similar with explicit casting, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.

```
class testc {
public:
    double x, y, z;

    testc(double x, double y, double z)
        :x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    testc omega(1, 2, 3);
    cout << *(double*)&omega << " " << *((double*)&omega +1) << " " << *((double*)&omega +2);
}
```

Comment: Do your members always have the same type?

Comment: I *think* `*((double*)&omega +1)` (you forgot the parenthesis) is a strict aliasing violation and UB, and it needs to be `*(double *)((char*)&omega + sizeof(double))`.

Comment: Don't do that even if it's possible. Re-design your class.

Comment: Technically, you could have `for (auto el : { omega.x, omega.y, omega.z }) {// your code}`. It is probably better to use a vector or an array container instead.

Comment: Sorry to see this one closed, I was just writing an answer using range-based for loop initialization statements (C++20) allowing us to used structured bindings as the init-statement: `for(auto [x, y, z] = omega; auto e : {x, y, z}) { std::cout << e << " "; }` (give or take some `auto` constness).

Comment: @dfri: I've reopened it. My answer is weak. Put in a placeholder to keep the dupe police at bay!

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks! (My answer doesn't really apply to the target as it seems to want to inspect an arbitrary number of unknowingly named members).

Comment: @Acorn `std::is_standard_layout_v` says it's standard-layout.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, never mind, I thought it had a private data member too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### (C++20) Looping over a known number of public members: structured bindings in a range-based for loop initialization statement

As of C++20 we may combine [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) with [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) initialization statements (the latter is a C++20 feature):

> **Grammar**
>
> for ( *init-statement(optional)* *range-declaration* : *range-expression* ) ...

Specifically, using structured bindings as the *init-statement* in a range-based for loop:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    double x, y, z;

    Foo(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

int main() {
    const Foo foo(1., 2., 3.);

    for (auto [x, y, z] = foo; auto e : {x, y, z}) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    } // 1 2 3

    return 0;
}
```

Note, however, that you can only use structured bindings to decompose public members of your class (in your example all members are public). Moreover, for the initializer list in the *range-expression* of the range based for loop, you may not have conflicting types, meaning this approach is limited to the context of your example: where all public members are of the same type.

#### Why use the structured bindings instead of just list-initializing the class members directly?

Now, if the (public) members of your class as well as the instance of it all have very brief names, we may want to consider omitting the structured bindings and instead list-initialize the class members directly:

```
const Foo f(1., 2., 3.);
for (auto e : {f.x, f.y, f.z}) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
} // 1 2 3
```

However, albeit arguably briefer, the drawback is that we no longer get any help from the compiler in spotting whether we've actually exactly decomposed all public members (no less, no more) or not, a check that is present when we use structured bindings:

```
for (auto [x, y] = foo; auto e : {x, y}) { /* ... */ }
// error: type 'Foo' decomposes into 3 elements, 
//        but only 2 names were provided

for (auto [x, y, z, xx] = foo; auto e : {x, y, z, xx}) { /* ... */ }
// error: type 'Foo' decomposes into 3 elements, 
//        but 4 names were provided
```

Comment: That's posh. Where does `omega` come into it?

Comment: @Bathsheba Ah sorry, I simply referred to the OP:s own example, but it's better if this is standalone, thanks.

Comment: Due to the fact this question was temporary closed as duplicate, I proposed the same solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059157/iterate-through-struct-and-class-members/62329191#62329191. However I'm interested if this approach can be extended to arbitrary number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (auto&& i : std::vector<double>{x, y, z}){
    // Do something, `i` is the double.
}
```

is one way, at the expense of creating a vector. I'm not convinced a compiler would detect this as an idiom and make optimisations either.

The behaviour of code like `*(&x + 1)` in order to attempt to reach `y` is undefined. (Pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays.)

Can't you use a `std::array` or a `std::vector` for `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: "The behaviour of code like *(&x + 1) in order to attempt to reach y is undefined. (Pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays.)"

Works fine on my end.

I dont want to declare a vector since Im looking for maximum efficiency.

I dont want to use an array since I want to access data members of an object in a natural way; obj.x, obj.y etc

Comment: @Skcoica: One manifestation of undefined behaviour is code appearing to work. But it's still UB and a good compiler will warn.

Comment: Can you give an example of a good compiler then ? Im using Visual Studio with default settings.

Comment: @Bathsheba Would `*(double*)((char*)&x + sizeof x)` be well-defined, or also UB?

Comment: @Skcoica You could check the documentation for how to turn on more (or any?) warnings during compilation.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: UB alas. In C you could put a `char[]` and the `double`s in a `union` and type-pun.

Comment: @Skcoica: MSVC is extremely permissive. And given the implementation of COM relies on such things, it's unlikely the MSVC devs would add warnings for this sort of stuff.

Comment: Why using `std::vector` instead of (`std::`)`initializer_list`? `for (auto&& i : {x, y, z})`?

Comment: *"UB alas"* Hmm. I've asked a [proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329008/is-it-ub-to-access-a-member-by-casting-an-object-pointer-to-char-adding-an) about this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Ooh - proper question. That's posh. Nice plug. I'll upvote it.