# Standard layout, taking address of member and indexing past it to next member

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Suppose we have a standard-layout class, simplified to this:

```
struct X {
    int num;
    Object obj; // also standard layout
    char buf[512];
};
```

As I understand it, if we have an instance of X, we can take its address and cast it to *char** and look at the content of X as if it was an array of bytes.

However, it's a little less clear if we do the following, taking the address of a member and walking *past* it as if we were walking through X itself:

```
X x;
char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x.obj) + sizeof(Object);
*((int*)p) = 1234; // write an int into buf
```

Is this valid and well defined?

I was commenting to a colleague that if we take the address of `obj` we should limit ourselves to the memory of that object, and not assume that reading past its end is safely going into the next field of the containing struct (`buf` in this case).  I have been asked to defend that statement.  In looking for an answer only managed to confuse myself a bit by all the similar questions that don't seem to address this precisely.  :)

Standard citations appreciated.  Also, I'd prefer to stick to the question "is this is valid", and ignore the question of its sensibility.

Comment: "Is this valid and well defined?" can't be, as you don't know about the relationship of the length of obj and alignment on your specific platform. Generally, once you lose the type information, very few things that you can do to your data are still "well-defined".

Comment: @MarcusMüller What is "the context of X"?  I provided the struct definition of X at the top.  Sorry if it wasn't clear that code was a continuation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks, that was a typo.  I meant `content`.  Fixed.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x.obj) + sizeof(Object)` violates https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#6.sentence-1, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62341088/ for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it, if we have an instance of X, we can take its address and cast it to char* and look at the content of X as if it was an array of bytes.

The standard doesn't actually allow this currently. Casting to `char*` will not change the pointer value (per [[expr.static.cast]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n486/expr.static.cast#13.sentence-4)) and as a result you will not be allowed to apply pointer arithmetic on it as it violates [[expr.add]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#4) and/or [[expr.add]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#6.sentence-1).

This is however often assumed to be allowed in practice and probably considered a defect in the standard. The paper [P1839](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1839r5.pdf) by Timur Doumler and Krystian Stasiowski is trying to address that.

But even applying the proposed wording in this paper (revision P1839R5)

```
X x;
char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x.obj) + sizeof(Object);
*((int*)p) = 1234; // write an int into buf
```

will have undefined behavior, at least assuming I am interpreting its proposed wording and examples correctly. (I might not be though.)

First of all, there is no guarantee that `buf` will be correctly aligned for an `int`. If it isn't, then the cast `(int*)p` will produce an unspecified pointer value. But also, there is no guarantee in general that there is no padding between `obj` and `buf`.

Even if you assume correct alignment and no padding, because e.g. you have guarantees from your ABI or compiler, there are still problems.

First, the proposal would only allow `unsigned char*`, not `char*` or `std::byte*`, to access the object representation. See "Known issues" section.

Second, after fixing that, `p` would be a pointer one-past the object representation of `obj`, so it doesn't point to an object. As a consequence the cast `(int*)p` cannot point to any `int` object that might have been implicitly created in `buf` when `X x;`'s lifetime started. Instead [[expr.static.cast]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.static.cast#13.sentence-4) will apply and the value of the pointer remains unchanged.

Trying to dereference the `int*` pointer pointing one-past-the-end of the object representation of `obj` will then cause undefined behavior (as it is not pointing to an object).

You also can't save this using `std::launder` on the pointer, because a pointer to an `int` nested inside `buf` would give you access to bytes which are not reachable through a pointer to the object representation of `buf`, violating `std::launder`'s precondition, see [[ptr.launder]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/ptr.launder#4).

---

In a broader picture, if you look at how e.g. `std::launder` is specified, it seems to me that the intention is definitively not to allow this. The way it is specified, it is impossible to use a pointer (in)to a member of a class (except the first if standard layout) to access memory of other (non-overlapping) members. This specifically seems to be intended to allow a compiler to do optimization by pointer analysis based on assuming that these other members are unreachable. (I don't know whether there is any compiler actually doing this though.)

Answer (score 1):

> I was commenting to a colleague that if we take the address of obj we should limit ourselves to the memory of that object,

Well said!

```
char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x.obj) + sizeof(Object);
```

Nope, `sizeof(Object)` isn't necessarily a multiple of your platform's alignment, so that the next member (`.buf`) might not necessarily start immediately at `.obj`'s end.

Generally, hm. If you really need to do this, *write a `union`* that's either a `char[512]` or a `int` or whatever you need it to be, and put it in place of `char buf[512]`; that's what they're for.

---

Taking your code and demonstrating this:

```cpp
#include "fmt/format.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Object {
  std::array<char, 17> values;
};
struct X {
  int num;
  Object obj; // also standard layout
  char buf[512];
};

int main() {
  X x;
  auto ptr_to_x = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x);
  auto ptr_distance = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x.buf) - ptr_to_x;

  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>> statements{
      {"instance x", sizeof(x)},
      {"class X", sizeof(X)},
      {"distance between beginning of X and buf", ptr_distance},
      {"Object", sizeof(Object)}};
  std::size_t maxlenkey = 0;
  std::size_t maxlenval = 0;
  for (const auto &[key, val] : statements) {
    maxlenkey = std::max(key.size(), maxlenkey);
    maxlenval = std::max(fmt::formatted_size("{:d}", val), maxlenval);
  }

  for (const auto &[key, value] : statements) {
    fmt::print("length of {: <{}s} {:{}d}\n", key, maxlenkey, value, maxlenval);
  }
}
```

prints:

```
length of instance x                              536
length of class X                                 536
length of distance between beginning of X and buf  21
length of Object                                   17
```

So, writing 4 bytes at `((char*)&x)+sizeof(Object)` will definitely not do the same as actually writing to `buf`.

Comment: that's wrong. See my amended answer!

Comment: But I really don't understand the difference between what I do here, showing that no, you can't just add something to the beginning of one member to get to the next, and what you want to do. We're not "reading" anything in that member object.

Comment: I'm disagreeing with your conclusion it "will definitely not do the same as actually writing to buf".  Your output shows that it is correctly computing the value.  "length of object" is 17, and `obj` it sits behind a 4-byte int, and `buf` is 21 bytes offset from the beginning, and 17+4.  Both ways compute the same value.  https://godbolt.org/z/qaPMEdrGf

I'm more interested in C++ standard citations than code snippets since the observed behavior in our code NOT incorrect, but I'd like to know precisely where the standards says it's not valid to compute it that way.  (And thanks!)