# Does reinterpret_cast together with binary input/output always leads to undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, file-io, pointer-arithmetic, reinterpret-cast, bit-cast

When working binary input/output, we often see/write code similar to this

```
in_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&obj), sizeof(obj))
out_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&obj), sizeof(obj))
```

Now, is there any guarantee within the standard that these operations do not lead to undefined behavior?
A clarification/explanation why it works would be appreciated.

#### Rational for the question:

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) (I hope I understood it correctly), casting T* to char*, unsigned char* and std::byte* and de-referencing the result should be legal. It explicitly states

> AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17) char, or unsigned char: this
> permits examination of the object representation of any object as an
> array of bytes.

Now what is not clear to me, is that sizeof(obj) part as well as *"examination of the object representation as an array of bytes"* imply that there is pointer arithmetic involved... which raises the question - is pointer arithmetic permitted by the standard? (In case of binary io I haven't looked at the actual implementations (they are a but unreadable to me at this point...), if there is alternative method used behind the scenes, feel free to clarify.

In case it does lead to undefined behavior, should `bit_cast` to `std::array` be preferred when doing binary IO?

I mean something like this:

```
auto binary_rep = std::bit_cast<std::array<const char, sizeof(obj)>>(obj);
out_file.write(&binary_rep[0], sizeof(obj));
```

for writing and

```
std::array<char, sizeof(obj)> binary_rep;
in_file.read(&binary_rep[0], sizeof(obj));
obj = bit_cast(binary_rep);
```

for reading?

Comment: This won't work as soon as you have a pointer (or container, etc.) in `obj`.

Comment: It *can* lead to undefined behaviour, depending on the type of `obj`  (e.g. is it a trivial type, etc?).   The layout of non-trivial class types (e.g. the class has non-trivial constructor/destructor, virtual functions, etc) is implementation defined and objects written using your approach aren't guaranteed to be read in correctly (particularly if the code that reads the object is built with a different compiler than the code which writes the object).   If the object contains pointers, writing and reading the pointer in different processes doesn't write/read the pointed-to data.

Comment: you mean `bit_cast` part? I think `reinterpret_cast` has the same flaw.

Comment: Your code is fine. The pointer arithmetic might not be [formally allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62341088/2752075) here, but this is a standard defect, nothing more.

Comment: It takes very little effort to write proper serialization functions for your class, that, if your type is a simple type, will get properly optimized by the compiler into the code you would expect, but also has the benefit of making your code easier to maintain.

Comment: Casting an object pointer to a `char*` pointer for the purpose of accessing the object's raw bytes is well-defined behavior in the C++ standard. On the other hand, performing I/O on an object that is not a trivial type with standard layout is undefined behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - do you mind do to give me a link? I could not find this part in the standard...