# Create mathematical vector with member variable like access for XYZW and RGBA

Tags: c++, vector, unions

I want to create a `Vector` class (not like the `std::vector` but a mathematical vector) which accepts template arguments for the underlying type and its size.

Accessing its elements would look like this:

```
// template <typename T, std::size_t N>
Vector<std::uint8_t, 3> vec{};

vec.x = 10;
vec.y = 12;
vec[2] = 14;

// if the size is 4: 
// vec.w = 16;
```

I want `.x`, `.y` and `.z` to be accessible if its size is 3 and `.w` with 4, but none of them if its size is smaller than 3 or larger than 4 and the same with RGBA. I don't want to have to use a method (like `.x()`), just accessing them like a normal member variable. In all cases I want to still be able to have my own subscript operator as well.

I had the idea to create a "base" `Vector` class which would contain all the general methods and then derive from it.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Vector {
};

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, 3> : Vector<T, 1> {
    union {
        T x, r;
    };
    union {
        T y, g;
    };
    union {
        T z, b;
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, 4> : Vector<T, 3> {
    union {
        T w, a;
    };
};
```

However to implement some of the methods (e.g. the subscript operator) I would need to have an array for the data (like `T data[N];`) in the "base" class. This would make the array and the unions to be different objects in memory and not work at all.

I now want to know if there are some ways I could achieve the wanted behavior without having do create some additional classes (like `Vector3<T>`) and having duplicate code for those `Vector`s with sizes from 2 to 4.

Comment: The `[]` can be overloaded. So, you're looking at a specialized class, no need for any unions, just plain fields with those elements, and an overloaded `operator[]`. A metric crapton of typing, but definitely doable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I do know about operator overloading, but how could I achieve to access the same data in `data[N]` with `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` (without function calls) when I am not using a `union`?

Comment: I wouldn't do it. The unions, while benign on the surface, don't work out of the box with non-trivial classes (those with non-trivial constructors/destructors), and while those rarely end up in a vector, it's still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to have an array as a member. You just need to implement `operator[]` and all the other operators (like `+`, `-`, etc.) become easy to implement in terms of that:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Vector {
    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const {
        // obtain pointer to the bytes of this object
        auto bytes = reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(this);
        // access the T object which is presumably stored at this byte offset
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(bytes + i * sizeof(T));
    }

    T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
        // One of the few safe use cases of const_cast:
        // Add an unnecessary const and remove it with const_cast.
        return const_cast<T&>(std::as_const(*this)[i]);
    }
};
```

This implementation makes the assumption that all the `T`s are laid out within the `struct` like an array, which is a reasonable assumption.
Note that `reinterpret_cast<T*>` would not be valid because `Vector` is not an array of `T`, and doing pointer arithmetic on such a pointer would be undefined behavior.

You can make sure that you have the right layout with:

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(Vector<int, 4>) == sizeof(int[4]));
```

If your type has an `operator[]` (however that is implemented, other operations become easy to implement.

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
Vector<T, N> operator+(const Vector<T, N>& a, const Vector<T, N>& b) {
    Vector<T, N> result;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

#### Note on `std::byte` pointer arithmetic

Doing pointer arithmetic on the underlying `std::byte` sequence of an object is technically undefined behavior, but this is more of a defect in the standard and no compiler enforces this. See:

- [Is it UB to access a member by casting an object pointer to `char *`, then doing `*(member_type*)(pointer + offset)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62329008/5740428)*
- [P1839R5: Accessing object representations](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1839r5.pdf) (C++ proposal)
- [P1839 Accessing Object Representations](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/592) (GitHub)

Comment: Thank you for this idea. When I implement my `Vector`s in a similar fashion as in my question (inheriting 4 from 3, but 3 from 0) and overload/specify (not sure about the term) those with 1, 2 and values above 4 I might get to the desired result. I am going to look into this tomorrow.

Comment: I would have preferred a switch over undefined behavior http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a61fc448d08a102f

Comment: @MooingDuck a `switch` requires extra work to be performed for each length, and doesn't produce optimal codegen. See https://godbolt.org/z/zPdE3TMs5. It's a possible solution, just far from optimal.

Comment: @JanSchultke: `mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]`  looks optimal to me https://godbolt.org/z/9WjG58E4n

Comment: @MooingDuck it gets optimized through inlining and constant propagation because this is a trivial example. You can easily come up with a not-so-trivial example: https://godbolt.org/z/bsYWx4Wrb The function using `switch` gets totally naive codegen wheras the one using `reinterpret_cast` gets vectorized operations. You'd likely see a significant difference in benchmarks. (tbf I think GCC is tripping here; it's not obvious that the vectorized version is better in this particular instance)

Comment: @JanSchultke: I had assumed that the caller would always be passing compile-time constants, because selecting x/y/z based on runtime values seemed unlikely. But you're right that it's an assumption I made. Without that, your points are correct.