How to iterate over different structs in C++ using a single function
I'm developing an Entity Component System (ECS) in C++ and I'm trying to find an efficient way to iterate over different component structs using a single function. Here's an example of my component structs:
struct PositionComponent {
    float x, y, z;
};

struct VelocityComponent {
    float vx, vy, vz;
};

struct RenderComponent {
    // rendering data
};

I want to create a generic function that can work with all of these component types, something like this:
ForEachComponentDo(function);

Where function would operate on each component, regardless of its type.
The key motivation for this approach is maintainability and scalability. When I add a new component type in the future, I want to avoid having to modify the core iteration logic or add new specialized functions for each new component as much as I can.
Thank you for your help!

It will be very likely your function will still depend on the content of the component.  What will your components have in common? In other words function would need to be able to call something that all compnents have in common (either an abstract baseclass or some trait/concept)

You mean something like std::for_each? Or a plain range for loop? But remember that all standard containers only store one type of object. You need inheritance and virtual functions and (smart) pointers to make it work. But then it becomes simple, really trivial, to do what you seem to want.

Iterating over members in a struct in a generic way requires reflection which standard c++ doesn't have at the moment. You can have a look at boost reflection library.

Do you need a single function to do the job for each structure, or you also want to have distinct functions for each type? There are many ways to do what you need: classic polymorphism, templated function, std::variant + visit, std::any with associated functions. You need to be a bit more specific with your question, maybe provide some example interfaces of your structures (like print() or render()) and example result of ForEachComponentDo.

Related, possible dup:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059157/iterate-through-struct-and-class-members    In short:  if you constrain the problem (e.g. so all the structs have the same number of public members and they are the same type) then there are options.    If you want a more generic solution, there is none, since it would require runtime reflection, which standard C++ doesn't (yet) have.

Most likely, you are about to make the wrong design decision. Anyway, here's a solution. (1) Your structures appear to be homogeneous in data type. This means that you can store them in a vector, in a base structure, over which you can use any iteration method you like. (2) You can use functions, in derived structures, to access elements at certain indices: float& x() {return vec[0];}. So, store the data in a vector and access the elements through functions with meaningful names. (3) Write generic functions that iterate over the vector in the base structure.

This is a very strange thing to want. Normally update functions are very specific on what component(s) they want to loop over. For example, entt allows you to write auto view = registry.view<const position, velocity>(); for "give me all (components of) entities that have a position and velocity".

To get a useful answer to this question, you need to give some idea of what you want to do to these different structures. Can you give an example of the kind of code you expect to be able to write in function. Doesn't have to be legal C++, just close enough to give an idea of what your expectations are. As already stated there is no totally generic solution, so the best solution depends on precisely what you want to do.

As a motivating example: can you write pseudocode on how you think you can use ForEachComponentDo to update entities' position components based on their velocity component?

Look into something like entt , there are a lot of tutorials in their site, try not to invent your own entity component system framework until you have a good grasp on the language, it can be a hard task.

Although you have no reflection in C++, you can in some cases and for "simple" cases do something close to want you seem to want.
This solution is based on the ideas found in this gist and mainly relies on struct binding.
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template< class T, class ...Args >
inline constexpr bool is_brace_constructible_v = requires { T {std::declval<Args>()...}; };

// We define a universal type.
struct any_type {  template<class T>   constexpr operator T();  };

template<class T, typename FUNCTION>
requires (std::is_class_v<std::decay_t<T>>)
constexpr auto class_fields_call (T&& object, FUNCTION&& f) noexcept
{
    using type = std::decay_t<T>;
    using at   = any_type;
    
    if constexpr(is_brace_constructible_v<type,at,at,at>)
    {
         auto&& [p1,p2,p3] = object;
         return f(p1,p2,p3);
    }
    else if constexpr(is_brace_constructible_v<type,at,at>)
    {
         auto&& [p1,p2] = object;
         return f(p1,p2);
    }
    else if constexpr(is_brace_constructible_v<type,at>)
    {
         auto&& [p1] = object;
         return f(p1);
    }  
}

/** Iterate the fields of a struct/class. Each field is given as argument to a provided functor.  */
template<class T, typename FUNCTION>
auto ForEachComponentDo (T&& object, FUNCTION&& fct) noexcept
{
    class_fields_call (std::forward<T>(object), [fct] (auto&&...args) { ( fct(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), ...); });
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct A {  int n; double x;  std::string s;  };

int main()
{
    A obj {123, 4.567, "uiop" };

    // We get the fields as an expansion pack
    class_fields_call (obj, [] (auto&&... fields)
    {
        ((std::cout << fields << ' '), ...);
    });
    std::cout << "\n";

    // We get each field as an argument of a function.
    ForEachComponentDo (obj, [] (auto&& field)
    {
        std::cout << field << " ";
    });
    std::cout << "\n";
}

Two functions are available:

class_fields_call that will allow to get the fields of a given struct instance as an expansion pack provided to a function provided by the user
ForEachComponentDo that will iterate each field through a user provided function

This solution is far from perfect and the main drawbacks are:

It can cope only with a maximum number N of struct attributes (here N=3) but it can be extended by code generating for bigger values of N; I suspect that a recursive version is achievable but I made no big effort to find one.
The types of the attributes to be iterated have to be constructible through brace initialization, which may raise issue (e.g. C arrays).

Demo

I think you have the OP's problem backwards.  They want to iterate over each component, not iterate over each member of a component.

For function to be a valid "for each" component, it needs to know how to consume each component if it acts on them differently.
For example, a function that moves everything left 10 pixels is going to be a noop on most componenets, but will operate on PositionComponent.
One approach you could consider is a type-erased std::function-like object that supports overloading.
template<class...Sigs>
struct function_view;

A function_view takes a callable object and type-erases creates a call for each of Sigs....
template<class...Fs>
struct overloaded:Fs... {
  using Fs::operator()...;
};

overloaded takes a bunch of callables and creates their overload set.
struct do_nothing_t {
  constexpr std::nullopt_t operator()(auto&&..., ...)const{return std::nullopt;}
};
constexpr do_nothing_t do_nothing = {};

do_nothing takes anything and throws it away.
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

this macro lets you create overload sets for a function easily.
#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) RETURNS( \
    (__VA_ARGS__)( std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ) \
  )

so OVERLOADS_OF(printf) is a function object that does an overload lookup of printf based on the arguments passed.
auto f = overloaded{ OVERLOADS_OF( eat_chicken ), do_nothing };

what f does (assuming no typos above) is that it tries to call eat_chicken on the passed in arguments.  If that fails, it simply returns std::nullopt.
You can use such an f to pass to a function_view< void(Comp1), void(Comp2), ... >.  If eat_chicken can take a Comp1 it is called; if no eat_chicken is defined on a component, the call of f(Comp77) is a noop.
So you'll have one spot where you define the list over components that your ForEachKindOfComponentDo you support.  This defines a function_view (or function_own or whatever) that supports those signatures.
At the point of use, you take a function object that has overloads for one, two, more, or all kinds of Components.  Whichever components are supported by the function object passed in, the function object is invoked on.  If the component is not supported by the function object passed in, the noop do_nothing_t is called and it is skipped.
Some operations make sense on every component, like "clone".  You literally are just using the copy constructor to create a copy of the struct somewhere else.
Some operations only make sense on some components, like "move 10 pixels left".  The ones that do support it will have overloads; the ones that are ignored do_nothing.
Some operations require custom code for a given operation, like maybe "serialize" or "print".  In that case, you omit the do_nothing and you'll get compile-time errors for unsupported components.
You can have a limited do_nothing, like physics_do_nothing and graphics_do_nothing, allowing some components to be skipped and others hard-checked at compile time to have support.
