# Any number of pointer to method using variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to have a variadic template class that should have any number of method pointers aka a compile-time list of method pointer. My goal was to achieve something like this:

```
struct SomeType : Invoke<&SomeType::foo, &SomeType::bar> {
    int foo(int i);
    double bar(double a, double b);
};
```

However, to accept any number of method with different parameter and return type, I came up with this:

```
template<typename T, T m>
struct Method;

template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args, R(T::f*)(Args...)>
struct Method<R(T::*)(Args...), f> {
    constexpr static auto method = f;
};
```

It work, but it forces me to use this syntax:

```
struct SomeType : Invoke<Method<decltype(&SomeType::foo), &SomeType::foo>, Method<decltype(&SomeType::bar), &SomeType::bar>> {
    int foo(int i);
    double bar(double a, double b);
};
```

With Invoke as this class:

```
template<typename... T>
struct Invoke;

template<typename First, typename... Others>
struct Invoke<First, Others...> : Invoke<Others...> {
    constexpr static auto method = First = First::method;
    using Next = Invoke<Others...>
};

template<>
struct Invoke<> {};
```

To get rid of the `decltype()`, the only way I found is not valid C++, but it would be:

```
template<T f, typename T>
struct Method;
```

So the compiler would guess the type of `f`.

How can I get closer to the syntax in the first code snippet? What would be an example of macro that is used like `INVOKE(&SomeType::foo)` and would expand to the code `Invoke<Method<decltype(&SomeType::foo), &SomeType::foo>>`?

Comment: Might be helpful to know what `Invoke` is and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Invoke implementation added

Comment: Invoke is supposed to hold a compile-time list of method

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031062/c-preprocessor-avoid-code-repetition-of-member-variable-list/11744832#11744832) might be useful

Comment: no way to escape the `decltype`, I'm afraid, though `Method`'s implementation could be simplified slightly. This is something the committee is working on.

Comment: @Sean I don't think I need full compile-time reflection. I want that list of method, but I just want those specified in the Invoke parameters.

Comment: I edited the question so that it is more specific