# Is it possible to auto-deduce the base class of a function template's template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to write a template function that would possess type information about the base class of the template argument? (assuming that the template argument derives from one class only)

So, I am looking for something like this:

```
template <class T> 
auto f(T t) -> decltype(...) { // ... is some SFINAE magic that 
                               //     catches B, the base of T
    std::cout << (B)t << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT**: Some relevant background. I am writing a generic implementation of the `A*` algorithm. The template argument is a `Node` structure. So, the user might define:

```
struct NodeBase {
    REFLECTABLE((double)g, (double)f)
        // Using the REFLECTABLE macro as described here:                    
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11744832/2725810 
};

struct NodeData : public NodeBase {
    using Base1 = NodeBase;
    REFLECTABLE((double)F)
};
```

I would like to write a function that prints the contents of the node structure. `REFLECTABLE` does all the hard work of extracting the fields of the `struct`. However, when the user gives me a `NodeData` instance, my function needs to print the contents of the `NodeBase` component as well. I would like to later add overloads of my function for two and three base classes.

Comment: do you have a list of potential base classes ?

Comment: This code will be part of a library, while T comes from the client. So, no.

Comment: You could add specialized `type_traits` with `template <> struct base_type<Derived1> { using type = Base1;};` or requiring CRTP to add type info in the class directly.

Comment: if you don't get a list of base classes, in case of multiple inheritance if you have `class B : private C, D {};` how would you know whether you want to choose `C` or `D` ?

Comment: please also add what you want to do with that, because it seems automatic base class detection might not be the right thing to do, or what do you do with the knowledge of the baseclass ?

Comment: @Alex I have added some background.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning consider using CRTP instead. then you can write template functions for a known baseclass. this will be a lot easier than detecting the baseclass.

Comment: @Alex I never used CRTP and am not sure how it is relevant here. If I understand correctly, CRTP is something like `class A : public X<A>`. What would be `X` and `A` in my case? Actually, would you please consider turning your comment into an answer, which would spell out a little more how CRTP can be applied here?

Comment: If you want user-assisted reflection, tell the users to supply metadata about both nembers abd bases. At the end of the day bases and members are the same thing.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm at work now I'll try to get a post in the evening.

Comment: @Alex I have created a question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34223547/2725810

Answer (score 1):

The SFINAE stuff you are looking for is in general not possible. What would you do for multiple inheritance? Private/protected inheritance? And I bet there are also more sophisticated problems I haven't thought about yet. The only way I see is by consistently using some reflection library (and not just a single macro), in which you can explicitly define the result you want to obtain.

Instead, the non-SFINAE and non-exciting way you might be looking for is to simply overload your function once for `NodeBase` and then pass the derived type via (const-)reference:

```
auto f(NodeBase const& t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

The call `f(NodeData{})` will then automatically get a reference to the base class `NodeBase`. Note that the reference is important here, otherwise you're slicing the derived object.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what are the types from which your classes can inherit, here is a method to dig all the actual base classes out for each instance.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

template<int i>
struct check: check<i+1> { };

template<>
struct check<3> { };

struct B1 { };
struct B2 { };
struct B3 { };

struct D: B1, B3 { };

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, B1>::value>::type
f(check<0>, T t) {
    B1 b1 = static_cast<B1>(t);
    std::cout << "B1" << std::endl;
    f(check<1>{}, t);
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, B2>::value>::type
f(check<1>, T t) {
    B2 b2 = static_cast<B2>(t);
    std::cout << "B2" << std::endl;
    f(check<2>{}, t);
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, B3>::value>::type
f(check<2>, T t) {
    B3 b3 = static_cast<B3>(t);
    std::cout << "B3" << std::endl;
    f(check<3>{}, t);
}

template<class T>
void f(check<3>, T) {
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}

template <class T> 
void f(T t) {
    f(check<0>{}, t);
}

int main() {
    D d;
    f(d);
}
```

Note how it skips the function involving `B2` because it is not a base type for `D`.
This method is also easy to extend if you have more than 3 types from which to inherit, it doesn't force fixed inheritance chains and you can perform different operations on different types.

Comment: I think you mean `std::is_base_of` rather than `std::is_convertible`.  `std::is_convertible<T, U>::value` will be `true` for example, if `T` has an overloaded cast operator to `U`.