# How does boost pfr get the names of fields of a struct?

Tags: c++, boost, reflection, c++20

In Boost 1.84 (currently [in progress](https://www.boost.org/users/history/in_progress.html)):

> Big new feature: field names reflection. Added new constexpr boost::pfr::get_name<N, T>() function that returns a std::string_view with a name of field at index N of an aggregate T. Requires C++20.

Using the [latest version of pfr on github](https://github.com/boostorg/pfr), you can write code like

```
#include <boost/pfr/core.hpp>
#include <boost/pfr/core_name.hpp>

struct S
{
    int i = 1;
    double d = 2;
    std::string s = "three";
};

const S s;
constexpr auto names = boost::pfr::names_as_array<S>();
boost::pfr::for_each_field(
    s,
    [&names](const auto& field, std::size_t idx)
    { std::cout << idx << ": " << names[idx] << " = " << field << '\n'; });
```

Output:

```
0: i = 1
1: d = 2
2: s = three
```

How does this work? This [blog post](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2020/10/01/reflection-for-aggregates/) explains how aggregate initialization can be repurposed to get the fields, but getting the field names seems like magic! But I get the above output on the big three compilers (latest Visual C++, gcc 13.2, clang 16). I'm no wiser looking at the code in [core_name20_static.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/pfr/blob/develop/include/boost/pfr/detail/core_name20_static.hpp).

Comment: note, trying the `get_name` [sample](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_pfr/short_examples_for_the_impatient.html) code, currently works on Visual C++, fails to build on clang with an error relating to `extern const T fake_object`, but works on gcc with `-fpermissive`.

Comment: With the type and index at hand, a nerdy trial & error algorithm can produce respecting member pointer values at compile-time. Feeding those values as NTTP to a function that returns `std::source_location`, it is possible to trim the extra bytes and get compile time constants.

Comment: Not what you seek, but This the original 1st hand stuff: https://youtu.be/UlNUNxLtBI0?feature=shared

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be familiar with [`boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex/examples.html#boost_typeindex.examples.getting_human_readable_and_mangl) or various automatic "Enum to string". These use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`/`__FUNCSIG__` to get the "prettified" function name (which includes writing out template parameters in full). Using this, we can get the name of a template parameter:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void test() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

template<auto V>
void test() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main() {
    test<std::string>();
    enum { a };
    test<a>();
}
```

```
// GCC output
void test() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
void test() [with auto V = main::a]
```

And you would remove the appropriate characters to get the "name" you want.

Before C++20, pointer/reference non-type template parameters had to point to complete objects. In C++20, they can now point to subobjects. So, you create an object and point to it:

```cpp
struct S
{
    int i = 1;
    double d = 2;
    std::string this_is_the_name_we_want = "three";
};

extern S fake_object;

template<auto* P>
void test() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main() {
    test<&fake_object.this_is_the_name_we_want>();
}
```

```
// GCC output
void test() [with auto* P = (& fake_object.S::this_is_the_name_we_want)]
```

(And you get a reference to each member using the same method as `boost::pfr::for_each_field`)

Comment: That's a really wonderful tutorial. I'd seen [getting type name using td::source_location::current() / __PRETTY_FUNCTION__](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490578) and understood it, but I hadn't made the jump to imagine using the same technique with NTTP! (I'm using [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) but haven't looked into the implementation. Thanks for explaining this as well!) It's a shame that we can't use something like `std::declval` in place of `fake_object`, or extend this to member function names. Roll on reflection in C++26!