# Map C++ exceptions to Result

Tags: c++, opencv, rust, ffi

I'm writing a Rust library which is a wrapper over a C++ library.

Here is the C++ side:

```cpp
#define Result(type,name) typedef struct { type value; const char* message; } name

extern "C" 
{
    Result(double, ResultDouble);

    ResultDouble myFunc() 
    {
        try
        {
            return ResultDouble{value: cv::someOpenCvMethod(), message: nullptr};
        }
        catch( cv::Exception& e )
        {
            const char* err_msg = e.what();
            return ResultDouble{value: 0, message: err_msg};
        }
    }
}
```

and corresponding Rust side:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct CResult<T> {
    value: T,
    message: *mut c_char,
}

extern "C" {
    fn myFunc() -> CResult<c_double>;
}

pub fn my_func() -> Result<f64, Cow<'static, str>> {
    let result = unsafe { myFunc() };
    if result.message.is_null() {
        Ok(result.value)
    } else {
        unsafe {
            let str = std::ffi::CString::from_raw(result.message);
            let err = match str.into_string() {
                Ok(message) => message.into(),
                _ => "Unknown error".into(),
            };
            Err(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions here:

1. Is it ok that I use `*const char` on C++ side but `*mut c_char` on Rust one? I need it because `CString::from_raw` requires mutable reference.
2. Should I use `CStr` instead? If yes, how should I manage its lifetime? Should I free this memory or maybe it has static lifetime?

Generally I just want to map a C++ exception which occurs in FFI call to Rust `Result<T,E>`

What is the idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: I would strongly recommend templates instead of macros for `Result`. A simple templated `struct`, with a type alias would work just fine. It's also not necessary to `typedef struct` in c++. `struct` are implicitly proper type names.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux IIRC templates cannot be used in `extern C` interfaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877705/why-cant-templates-be-within-extern-c-blocks

Comment: I hadn't noticed it was `extern C`.

Comment: The documentation on [`CString::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.from_raw) already answers the first part of the question: _"This should only ever be called with a pointer that was earlier obtained by calling into_raw on a `CString`"_. This question is then narrowed down to returning an owning string from C into Rust code.

Comment: @E_net4 when I saw OpenCV examples from documentation ([link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/intro.html#error-handling)) I didn't see they free `e.what()` so probably it's a static string which can be safely converted into `CStr`. But i'm not sure. However, I see your point, good catch.

Comment: In C++, exceptions and their contents are already freed automatically. The `what` member function usually either returns a static string or returns a pointer to a string that was previously built and kept as a member of the exception. In OpenCV, it seems to be the latter. I'm afraid that it is not safe to return that pointer in particular.

Comment: Are `try`/`catch` allowed in `extern "C"` sections since `try` and `catch` are not in the C language?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think it's ok since it isn't used in public API.

Comment: Can you check whether that `return ResultDouble{value: cv::someOpenCvMethod(), message: nullptr};` compiles? I don't think naming the arguments like that is valid C++.

Comment: @E_net4 i'm sure it does and I actually get the error message on rust side: `running 1 test
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (A.size == arrays[i0]->size) in init, file C:\Users\Alex\Documents\foo\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 4845
error: test failed, to rerun pass '--test test_imgproc'
`. I think it's works because of gcc, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101575/2559709)

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: That's not C initializer syntax. Designated initializers would look like `{.value = ..., .message = ...}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Is it ok that I use *const char on C++ side but *mut c_char on Rust one? I need it because CString::from_raw requires mutable reference.

The documentation on [`CString::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.from_raw) already answers the first part of the question:

> "This should only ever be called with a pointer that was earlier obtained by calling into_raw on a `CString`".

Attempting to use a pointer to a string which was not created by `CString` is inappropriate here, and will eat your laundry.

> 2. Should I use CStr instead? If yes, how should I manage its lifetime? Should I free this memory or maybe it has static lifetime?

If the returned C-style string is guaranteed to have a static lifetime (as in, it has [static duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration)), then you could create a `&'static CStr` from it and return that. However, this is not the case: [`cv::Exception`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d1/dee/classcv_1_1Exception.html) contains multiple members, some of which are owning string objects. Once the program leaves the scope of `myFunc`, the caught exception object `e` is destroyed, and so, anything that came from `what()` is invalidated.

```
        const char* err_msg = e.what();
        return ResultDouble{0, err_msg}; // oops! a dangling pointer is returned
```

While it is possible to transfer values across the FFI boundary, the responsibility of ownership should always stay at the source of that value. In other words, if the C++ code is creating exceptions and we want to provide that information to Rust code, then it's the C++ code that must retain that value and free it in the end. I took the liberty of choosing one possible approach below.

By following [this question on duplicating C strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9593798/1233251), we can reimplement `myFunc` to store the string in a dynamically allocated array:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

ResultDouble myFunc() 
{
    try
    {
        return ResultDouble{value: cv::someOpenCvMethod(), message: nullptr};
    }
    catch( cv::Exception& e )
    {
        const char* err_msg = e.what();
        auto len = std::strlen(err_msg);
        auto retained_err = new char[len + 1];
        std::strcpy(retained_err, err_msg);
        return ResultDouble{value: 0, message: retained_err};
    }
}
```

This makes it so that we are returning a pointer to valid memory. Then, a new public function will have to be exposed to free the result:

```cpp
// in extern "C"
void free_result(ResultDouble* res) {
    delete[] res->message;
}
```

In Rust-land, we'll retain a copy of the same string with the approach described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24145823/1233251). Once that is done, we no longer need the contents of `result`, and so it can be freed with an FFI function call to `free_result`. Handling the outcome of `to_str()` without `unwrap` is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
extern "C" {
    fn myFunc() -> CResult<c_double>;
    fn free_result(res: *mut CResult<c_double>);
}

pub fn my_func() -> Result<f64, String> {
    let result = unsafe {
        myFunc()
    };
    if result.message.is_null() {
        Ok(result.value)
    } else {
        unsafe {
            let s = std::ffi::CStr::from_ptr(result.message);
            let str_slice: &str = c_str.to_str().unwrap();
            free_result(&mut result);
            Err(str_slice.to_owned())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want C-strings, I suggest you use C-like code instead. The entire catch clause can be rewritten: `return ResultDouble{0, std::strdup(e.what())};`, then you have to rewrite the body of `free_result` to `std::free(res->message);`.

Comment: The `str_slice` you create on the Rust side is never used... I think it's a left-over. Or that there is a mix-up as `s` is not a `String`.

Comment: @MatthiewM I deliberately avoided `strdup` because it is not ISO C (although it should work in practice, all right). As for the `str_slice `, yep, I meant to return it instead of `s`. That's fixed.

Comment: @E_net4 nice one. However, your `exercise to the reader` has been already solved in the question :)

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Well, yet another reason to omit the solution here for brevity. :)